# std::make_heap with pairs

Tags: c++, data-structures, std-pair

Is it possible to do `make_heap()` with a pair in a vector?

I'm using:

```
 std::vector< std::pair < int , tablero& > > lista_abierta_;
```

I use the object function to order the pair by the first member, but it crashes.

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include "8_puzzle.h"
#include "tablero.h"

using namespace std;

class comp {
public:
    bool operator()(pair < int, tablero&> a, pair < int, tablero&> b) const {
        return a.first > b.first;
    }
};

pair < int, tablero& > puzzle::A_estrella::tope()
{
    pair < int, tablero& > l=lista_abierta_.front();

    pop_heap(lista_abierta_.begin(),lista_abierta_.end());
    lista_abierta_.pop_back();

    return l;
}
```

[Taken from [here](http://pastebin.com/nJS2DuZP)]

Comment: Hi nsb, welcome to stack overflow. Please try and format your post according to the [formatting guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Thanks.

Comment: You can´t have a `pair` which contains a _reference_ inside a standard container, can you?

Comment: @K-ballo I had the same problem with reference. pair<int, std::reference_wrapper<tablero> > will fix some issues regarding copy inside pop_heap/make_heap.

Answer (score 1):

As long as `std::pair<T, U>` provides `operator<` (meaning : `T` and `U` provide `operator<`), I don't see any issue in using make_heap.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `std::make_heap<T>` as long as `T` provides `bool operator<(const T &, const T &)` or you explicitly pass comparer.

You have to change line 23 from

```
pop_heap(lista_abierta_.begin(),lista_abierta_.end());
```

to

```
pop_heap(lista_abierta_.begin(),lista_abierta_.end(), comp());
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is reference like `pair < int, tablero& >` won't work in case of copy inside `make_heap`/`pop_heap` . To fix that we need `pair<int, std::reference_wrapper<tablero> >`. The `comp` and other implementations need to be changed accordingly.

```
class comp {
public:
    bool operator()(pair < int, std::reference_wrapper<tablero> > a, pair < int, std::reference_wrapper<tablero> > b) const {
        return a.first > b.first;
    }
};
```

And `heap_pop` and `make_heap` will require an object of `Compare`.

```
comp mycomp;
pop_heap(lista_abierta_.begin(),lista_abierta_.end(),mycomp);
```